# Reduce number of malloc() calls

Tags: c

Say I have a program that allocates a chunk of memory

```
char* get_date() {
    char* date = malloc(100);
    return date;
}
```

And I want to call the function *a considerable number of times* in the main function.

```
int main() {

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        char *c = get_date();

        //do something

        free(c);
   }

    return 1;
}
```

How can I reduce the number of times a new chunk of memory is allocated and just allocate one and overwrite it afterwards?
Somebody told me about something like this:

```
char *date = malloc(100);
for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

    char *c = get_date(date):
    //do something
}
free(date);
```

But I am not sure how the new function, *get_date* should look like and why it should work.

Comment: this is not a homework or anything related...

Comment: Somebody is simply right (if you then remove the `malloc` in `get_date`, of course)

Comment: @StephanLechner If you modify `get_date` by removing `char* date = malloc(100);`.

Comment: First, `char* void` isn't a thing. Second, you `free()` dynamically allocated memory once you no longer need it. Third, dynamically allocating a date doesn't make a lot of sense, you should make a data type for it and pass it by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having `get_date` *return* a pointer to the buffer with the data produced by the function, make it *take* a pointer to a buffer into which the data will be written. I.e. the prototype of `get_date` could be something like

```
void get_date(char *buf);
```

However, it might be useful for get_date() to be able to tell not only the starting address of the buffer but also the size of the buffer . That way,
 the function can tell if the given buffer is too small (and then return e.g. an `int` indicating an error code). Hence, the prototype

```
int get_date(char *buf, size_t len);
```

might be more useful in practice.

On the caller side, you could then use e.g.

```
char date[100];
for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    // return value 0 means success
    if (get_date(date, sizeof date) == 0) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I.e. in this case, you wouldn't need `malloc` or `free` at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to save 10,000 malloc / free calls?

Before you change your code, measure how long it takes. If you are too lazy to measure it, then the speed is not important, so don't change it.

Comment: This answer is the only one (among other provided) suggests to have a baseline before performance optimisation. Given it is required for every optimisation, why was it downvoted? :-S

Comment: @zerkms: Not the downvoter and you are very right about not doing premature optimisations. Nevertheless, this does not answer the question and should better be a comment to the (unnecessary) question.

Comment: @Olaf totally. Does not deserve a downvote. But every other question should be prepended with "Make a performance baseline to know whether your change made anything better"

Answer (score 0):

100 bytes?  Why are you using `malloc()` at all?

```
for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

    char c[100]:
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have a function that returns temporary fixed size memory, the memory can be static:

```
thread_local char get_date_buffer [100];

char* get_date() {
    // change get_date_buffer...
    return get_date_buffer;
};
```

You must not free the return value and you must copy the data when reusing it and recalling the function. Many api-functions use this technique, like `glGetString`.

Comment: Be careful with this approach - it's not multithread-safe.

Comment: Now, the array should be allocated per thread in the thread local section. It should not matter in this case if you have a single variable or an fixed size array, because the array is just like writing a hundred times ``thread_local char c0, c1, c2, ...``.